# Errors changing the Identity SQL storage (official tutorial)

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Following the official tutorial (http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider) I've created a new MVC project and all files I need (MySqlHistoryContext, etc.). There aren't problems here, but the tutorial press 'run' and all is correct, and I press 'run' and obtain the errors in the screenshoot.

The template has defined the "ApplicationUserManager" class, so the solved threads in StackOverflow aren't useful for me.

[image: Screenshoot]

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Test2-20150517124010.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Test2-20150517124010;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=users;Uid=root;Pwd=Password1;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
        invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.2.0"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you specify what errors you get? It's unreadable from the screenshot.

Comment: You can "Right click -> View image" and see it perfectly :)

Comment: I'm using the app. There is no right click

Comment: Ok, this is the link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0lyXz.png

Answer (score 1):

Joe,  I think this tutorial is out of date and that is at issue here.

There is a comment on the tutorial that points to someone who has done this more recently.  This may help.  http://k16c.eu/2014/10/12/asp-net-identity-2-0-mariadb/

A side note: The most current version of Connector/NET supports EF migrations.  When the tutorial was created - as it states - MySQL did not support migration.  Since Connector/NET supports EF migrations it stands to reason that the latest version of MYSQL.Data.Entities would support it as well.  Therefore you may not have to include the changes to the HistoryContext as described in these tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Joe,

After looking at your code, the connection string smells funny to me.  Are you sure thats the correct string.  LocaldB is a SQL thing.  It is the VS default and definitely  not a MySql db.

I've have looked at many tutorials using MySql db with Identity.  None of them use a string like that.

The MySql dev website lists a correct connection strings.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApplicationDbContext` class is missing a static `Create` method.

For example:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Further, your `ApplicationUser` class is missing a `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method.  For example:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {

    var userIdentity = 
        await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, 
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tested too, but if I add this code and run the project, I get an InvalidOperationException: http://i.stack.imgur.com/r7VYw.png

Comment: Please post your `web.config`.  In the future, please copy  error messages and post them, rather then using screenshots.  Makes life easier for everyone concerned.

Comment: And the rest of the error message from the last screenshot?  Half the message is truncated...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiarized with VS. "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information"

Comment: I must add a comment: I've added "Version=6.7.2.0" because the tutorial says it, but I don't know (and how put, because I havent any reference) if I have the correct version.

Comment: It's definitely possible given the age of the tutorial that the version has changed.  In the project references, check the properties of the MySQL reference.  Update the version in the `web.config` to match.  From what I can tell, you are using version `6.9.6.0`

Comment: I understand, but if I search in "References" by "mysql", VS says "no items found", and if I search in nuget packages -> online -> mysql: "MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity, MySQL.Data.Entities.MySql.Web, MySql.Fabric" created by Oracle and MySQL. Must I install something?